# Increment error: Python

Tags: python, increment

so here's my code:

```
def create(t):
    if len (t[0]) != len (t[1]):
        raise ValueError ('something')
    for i in range (1):
        for j in range (len(t[0])-1):
            if sum (t[i][j]) + (len (t[i][j])-1) >= len (t[0]):
                raise ValueError ('something')
            else:
                return (t)
```

What I tried:

```
t = (((2,), (3,), (2, 3),), ((2,), (3,), (3,)))
```

Originally I thought the problem was that i and j aren't incrementing for some reason but maybe it's the second if clause that's being ignored (possibly poor written)? 
Thanks a lot in advance, and sorry for noob question :s

Comment: `for i in range (1)` doesn't look right to me. `i` will only ever be zero if you do that. Also, a function terminates immediately when it encounters a `return` statement, so if the `else` clause executes, that will be the end of the `j` loop. With a `raise` in one branch and a `return` in another, it's not surprising that j never increases past 0.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Kevin you're right, I always get that mixed up! return should always be in the same line as "def". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first guess was correct: `i` and `j` aren't incrementing.

The inner loop causes the function to exit on the very first iteration. The inner loop is guaranteed to either `raise`, which exits the function, or `return`, which exits the function.  Also, `for i in range(1)` only does one iteration, with `i==0`.

Perhaps (I say perhaps, because I have no idea what your function is *supposed* to do) the solution is to get rid of the `else` and outdent the `return` three stops.

Additionally, the `range(len(t[0])-1)` is probably wrong. Try `range(len(t[i]))`:

```
def create(t):
    if len (t[0]) != len (t[1]):
        raise ValueError ('something')
    for i in range (1):
        for j in range (len(t[i])):
            print (i,j)
            if sum (t[i][j]) + (len (t[i][j])-1) > len (t[0]):
                raise ValueError ('something')
    return (t)

t = (((2,), (3,), (2, 3),), ((2,), (3,), (3,)))
print (create(t))
```

Comment: I did that plus removed the equal sign in the comparison on the if clause. It still doesn't return an error with the example (and it should cause sum(t[0][2]) +  len(t[0][2]) -1 is greater than len(t[0])

Comment: That's irrelevant since `j` never takes on a value of `2`. `for j in range(len(t[0])-1):` evaluates to (in your example) `for j in range(2):`

Comment: Oh I see, same problem that I had on my original code with the range(1). Thank you very much. For your time and pacience